# AutomationElement NativeWindowHandle x64 Compatibility

Tags: c#, int, ui-automation, intptr

When testing Microsoft UIAutomationClient's AutomationElements, I discovered that the AutomationElementInformation NativeWindowHandle getter returns int as per [spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.nativewindowhandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and shown in following example:

```
        var ae = AutomationElement.FromHandle(new IntPtr(0x35100C));
        MessageBox.Show(ae.Current.NativeWindowHandle.ToString("X8"));
```

In my above sample, I just took the largest random handle I could find in my x64 system. Currently, the values are low enough to fit in a int type (32 bits). Based off my research, it should actually return IntPtr since IntPtr can handle larger values found in x64 systems.

Now for my questions:

1. Will the largest possible handle in a Windows x64 system 
   fit into the int32 returned by NativeWindowHandle?
2. If not, what should I do to mitigate this problem?

---

Update #1:
Any authoritative links (i.e. MSDN, etc) to what @HansPassant mentioned regarding Windows' keeping handles less than int.MaxValue for compatibility reasons would be great.

Comment: It is a bit sloppy, but it will work in practice.  Current versions of Windows keep window handle values less than int.MaxValue for compatibility reasons.  Well, like this one :)  You can't fix it of course, it is not your code.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have a reference link? I can refer to it if I face this problem in future implementations. I would also accept your answer if you post. Thanks.